# Does anyone recognize this chip? B9930 FLC5068

Tags: motor, identification, robot

[image: photo of unknown device]

I can't find it. Does anyone recognize this logo?

Comment: Do you have any context around it? What other components or inputs/outputs is it connected to? What power supplies does it appear to be supplied by? Any remarkable passives, discrete parts, or other, known chips connected with to one in a significant way?

Answer (score 6):

It's an [EMB9930G](http://www.excelliancemos.com/download_prod_s.php?ds=42&file=2) Dual-N/Dual-P Logic level MOSFET array, in the structure of a standard H-Bridge. The package is a SOP-8.

The manufacturer is "Excelliance MOS Corporation".

[image: Device Marking]

- B9930 is the part number marking.
- FLC5068 is a date code for manufacture.

Comment: For those wondering, the part was found by simply typing "B9930 soic-8" into google - it was practically the first link.

Comment: god! fast answer! thanks a lot!!